# Lenovo Flex 3 Pen support

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen, lenovo-laptop, pen, stylus

I just bought the Lenovo Flex 3, mainly for the touch screen.  I am also hoping to pick up a pressure sensitive pen for use with Bamboo Paper and Adobe Illustrator.

I am having problems finding anything on compatibility on Google and was hoping the community could possibly help.  Does anyone know if pressure sensitive pens will work on the Flex 3, or is this only going to work with the rubber tip style pens?

Lenovo has that AnyPen software, but I'm not sure if it is active with the laptop.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: It is not advertised to support that, so I say no.

Comment: can you add this as an answer so i can mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

It is not advertised to support that, so I say no.